# Dvorak Setting on Mac OS X 10.5.8 for Right Hand or Left Hand only

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, dvorak

I use Macbook Pro 13", Mac OS X 10.5.8, and I mostly only use the keyboard on my mac. There are only two Dvorak Settings. I only use standard Dvorak so far. How can I enable Dvorak for right hand or left hand only?

Here is my dvorak setting screenshot on my mac:

[image: dvorak settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Snow Leopard. Here's my screenshot of keyboard layouts in OS X 10.6.2. Otherwise, I found a link that I haven't tried for adding [left- and right-handed Dvorak layouts to OS X](http://dvorak.mwbrooks.com/mac.html).

[image: Notice the left- and right-handed Dvorak keyboard layouts]